# CSS Animation property stays after animating

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to get a CSS animation property to stay after completing, is this possible?

This is what I'm trying to achieve...

The element should be hidden when the user lands on the page, after 3 seconds (or whatever), it should fade in and once the animation has completed it should stay there.

Here is a fiddle attempt...
http://jsfiddle.net/GZx6F/

Here is the code for preservation...

```
<h2>Test</h2>

<style>
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
}

h2 {
    animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 3s;
}
</style>
```

I know how to do this with jQuery.. it would be like this...

```
<h2>test</h2>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('h2').hide().delay(3000).fadeIn(3000)
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_keyframes.asp) outdated? It says Chrome and FireFox only support alternatives.

Comment: @iambriansreed: I always assume it is :)

Comment: @iambriansreed don't even click w3schools search results. If you accidentally do, look away from your monitor and press the back button on your mouse.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

I think you're looking for `animation-fill-mode` CSS3 property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/animation-fill-mode

> The animation-fill-mode CSS property specifies how a CSS animation should apply styles to its target before and after it is executing.

for your purpose just try to set

```
h2 {
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}
```

Setting *forwards* value «the target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution»

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio, that's great, I'll accept that answer. Just one odd thing is happening that I wonder whether you know anything about - on iOS (haven't tested anything else), the countdown to the ease-in is paused whenever I scroll, e.g. if I start scrolling straight away when the page loads it doesn't fade in. But when I STOP scrolling the 3s starts counting down. Is this just default iOS behaviour? Thanks

Comment: Is this available in raw SVG animation?

Answer (score 20):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9774884/1250044) of [@Fabrizio Calderan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098851/fabrizio-calderan), it has to be said that you can even apply the `animation-fill-mode` property `forwards` directly to `animation`. So the following should also work:

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 3s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<h2>Test</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you want the animation to remain in the final state .
I would use fill mode

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

How to animate an element and get it to stay as the animation is done:

```js
// Beggin
```

```css
#box {
  /* Give it a width, a height and a background so can see it  */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /* Unimportant styling */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 30%, #fcfcfc 40%, #f8f8f8 50%, #f0f0f0 100%);
  
  /* Starts here: */
  opacity: 0;
  animation: yourName 2800ms ease-in-out 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes yourName {
  0% /* (from) */ {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% /* (to) */ {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar happening to me. I added position:relative to the element that was animating and that fixed it for me.