# How do I use css transitions to scale an image and move it at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I have a logo on my page which I want to be large in the center of the page for a few seconds before scaling down and moving to its place in the top left hand corner. I have managed to achieve the move i like but I have tried many different things to achieve the scale and not been able to. This is my code

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: myMove 3s;
    -moz-animation: myMove 3s;
    -o-animation: myMove 3s;
    animation: myMove 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myMove {
    0%   {top:350px; left:450px;}
    25%  {top:350px; left:450px;}
    50% {top:350px; left:450px;}
    100% {top:0px; left:0px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes myMove {
    0%   {top:350px; left:450px;}
    25%  {top:350px; left:450px;}
    50% {top:350px; left:450px;}
    100% {top:0px; left:0px;}
}

@-o-keyframes myMove {
    0%   {top:350px; left:450px;}
    25%  {top:350px; left:450px;}
    50% {top:350px; left:450px;}
    100% {top:0px; left:0px;}
}

@keyframes myMove {
    0%   {top:350px; left:450px;}
    25%  {top:350px; left:450px;}
    50% {top:350px; left:450px;}
    100% {top:0px; left:0px;}
}
```

any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Codepen example**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fipaL

---

Instead of top and left properties you shoud use `translate3d` CSS3 property, so to get full benefit of GPU acceleration. For the image scaling you can also use `scale()` transformation, e.g.

```
.logo {

    position: absolute;

    /* set initial position here */
    top: 350px;
    left: 450px;

    -webkit-animation: myMove 3s;
    -moz-animation: myMove 3s;
    -o-animation: myMove 3s;
    animation: myMove 3s;

}

@-webkit-keyframes myMove {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    50%  { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(.5), translate3d(-450px, -350px, 0);} 
}



/* insert here the same code with browser-vendor prefixes */
...
```

Comment: thank you very much!! just one more question, how do I stop the logo returning to its original state at the end of the animation? at the moment it goes straight back to large in the middle !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774829/css-animation-property-stays-after-animating