# How to persist css3 animation change

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

Goal is to keep the background red at the end of the animation.

**Using chrome**
http://codepen.io/JulianNorton/pen/RNqLZM

```
.animation {
    -webkit-animation:test-animation 2s 2;
    // Animation stops after a few seconds, state doesn't stay red.
}


@-webkit-keyframes test-animation {
    0% {

        background-color:#fff
    }

    100% {
        background-color:red
    }
}

@keyframes test-animation {
    0% {
        background-color:#fff
    }

    100% {
        background-color:red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

is most likely what you were looking for.
Source:
[CSS Animation property stays after animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774829/css-animation-property-stays-after-animating)

Comment: http://codepen.io/JulianNorton/pen/EaOwpW
Thank you for this, at first I thought this wasn't the answer, but I had forgotten to add -webkit.

Comment: You are welcome. It's always the details that fix it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the background color of your `.animation` element to red. Since the keyframe animation is triggered automatically, it will not appear red at first, but white like you want.